# Subfolder and package in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have the following folder structure in windows:

src/MAS/Folder1

src/MAS/Folder2

In Folder1 and Folder2 there are .java files and also in the folder MAS there are some .java-files.

Somehow in the package explorer in eclipse this looks different. I have:

src/MAS

src/MAS.Folder1

Folder2 is in Eclipse within MAS and not MAS.Folder2. How can I change that because I am getting error messages in the .java-files of Folder2 saying that the declared package does not match the expected package. What I want to have is:

src/MAS

src/MAS.Folder1

src/MAS.Folder2

Thanks in advance. I'd really appreciate your input since I am not an expert.

Comment: In Java it is mandatory that the class `com.example.foo.Bar` must be declared in the file `Bar.java` in the subfolder `com/example/foo`. In Eclipse, subfolders of a source folder are displayed as packages, e. g. `src/com/example/foo` as `src/com.example.foo` (package `com.example.foo` in source folder `src`). Source folders can be configured in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Source_.

Comment: And the standard Java naming conventions for packages (and thus their corresponding flders) is to be in all lowercase, and to start with your internet domain in reverse order, to avoid name clashes. So it should be com.yourcompany.mas.folder1, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Unforunately I still do not understand what I have to do in order to solver the problem. I tried to add the folder src/MAS/Folder2 in the Java Build path of the project. When I clicked on "Add Folder" and choose Folder2 (which is in src/MAS/Folder2) the src/MAS/Folder2 is shown in Eclipse as a subfolder of the whole Project and I receive an error message in every .java file stating "the declared package Mas does not match the expected package "". When I try to link the sources in the BuildPath of the preoject in Eclipse Folder2  is directly a subfolder of the project